# Are there algorithms to cluster Graphs, not just cluster nodes in a graph?

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering, graph-theory

I am wondering if there are algorithms to cluster graphs; what I meant is to cluster many graphs, not cluster the nodes in a graph.

For example, we have N graphs, G1, G2, G3, .....GN. Then we can identify [G1, G2, G3] have high similarity in topology, [G4, G5] another one, and so on.

Comment: Is there something inadequate about extracting features from the graphs and clustering on those numbers?

Comment: @Dave we will use features like node labels.

Comment: If you opt for clustering with a pre-calculated distance matrix (see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/2717), ht @Sextus Empiricus) you may use various measures of graph distances. Many of them rely on having label-matched graphs or at least the same number of nodes. If your graphs are unlabeled and of different sizes, you can use the NetSimile method [(Berlingerio et al. 2012)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.2684) that models graphs as distributions of local characteristics with which you can calculate distances. I've done a similar thing [in a paper](https://doi.org/10.1162/netn_a_00211).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The main problem here seems to me to be about defining and finding the [(dis)similarity between different graphs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_matching).

- The 'graph edit distance' (defining distance in terms of number of operations neccesary to convert one graph into the other) is a common way that has been described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16399597/edit-distance-between-two-graphs) on stack overflow.
- In section 4.2 of "Exact and inexact graph matching: methodology and applications" you find alternative methods for inexact graph matching.

  These are: artificial neural networks, relaxation labeling, spectral methods and kernel methods.

  Riesen, Kaspar, Xiaoyi Jiang, and Horst Bunke. "Exact and inexact graph matching: Methodology and applications." Managing and Mining Graph Data (2010): 217-247.

Then, after solving that problem, to perform clustering you can use any clustering method that uses a  [distance matrix](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_matrix).

- See this question: [Clustering with a distance matrix](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2717/clustering-with-a-distance-matrix)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you suggesting, that if we have N graphs, we can compute `graph edit distance` for every paired graphs, and then form a NxN `distance matrix`. Then use the above clustering method as you list above for further clustering `distance matrix`?

Comment: @TripleH yes, we make a matrix with all pairwise distances and based in the matrix we perform the clustering. Now that you state it like that it sounds to me that this can require a lot of computations. Possibly the NxN matrix can also be made sparse as an alternative.

Comment: Thanks again. I found an interesting suggestion from early's discussions ([How to cluster graphs with same topology, but different weights on the vertices?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/307962/how-to-cluster-graphs-with-same-topology-but-different-weights-on-the-vertices) and 
    [Algorithms for Graphs Clustering](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/384343/algorithms-for-graphs-clustering)): we can find the embedding vectors of each graph and then apply Euclidian distance clustering for clustering.  Have you tried this idea?

Comment: @TripleH I have never tried this idea with clustering graphs but clustering based on a distance matrix is very common and I used [hierarchical clustering](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_clustering) along with the correlation matrix that goes along with PCA.